# "Network read bytes" in Azure App metrics?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I cannot find the meaning of the "Network read bytes" site metric for Azure App Service.

[image: Site Metrics]

It isn't documented on [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics).

Can someone explain what it is?

Comment: I/O Read Bytes - The number of bytes read in input/output operations generated by a process, including file, network, and device I/Os. I/O Read Bytes directed to CONSOLE (console input object) handles are not counted. By this definition I believe this perf counter shows only the network I/O category only.